# How to get individual field of document

Tags: android, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

This code retrieves all documents in `user/sets` with date between `greaterThan` and `lessThan`. I'm using Cloud Firestore.

```
    Query dbSets = db.collection("users")
            .document(id)
            .collection("sets")
            .whereLessThan("date", lessThan);
    dbSets
            .whereGreaterThanOrEqualTo("date", greaterThan)
            .get()
            .addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<QuerySnapshot>() {
                @Override
                public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<QuerySnapshot> task) {
                    if (task.isSuccessful()) {
                        for (QueryDocumentSnapshot document : task.getResult()) {
                            log(document.getData().toString()+document.getId());
                        }
                    }
                }
            });
```

This code produces this in the log:

```
{date=Mon Jul 02 00:00:00 GMT+02:00 2018, name=Hanna, nc=true, inst=true}p1kr3Y34mu50NRNXjvno
```

What should I do to get the value of an individual field? For example:

```
document.getData().get("name") // outputs "Hanna"
```

I can't find any documentation on this (is it because Cloud Firestore is still in Beta?).

Comment: *I can't find any documentation* you mean you can't find `Map<String, Object>` documentation?

Comment: Well, how was I supposed to know that it returns a `Map` object? I couldn't find any documentation about what `getData()` actually returns.

Comment: Well, how you could not find it when it is on https://firebase.google.com/docs ?

Answer (score 0):

Turns out my example solution was the correct way to do it:

```
log(document.getData().get("name")+document.getId());
```

outputs:

```
Hannap1kr3Y34mu50NRNXjvno
```

The relevant docs: https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/firestore/QueryDocumentSnapshot